# Starting hosted network on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I am trying to start a hosted network on Windows 10. First I run this command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Test_Network key=password keyUsage=persistent
```

It runs fine. However, when I run

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I get an error saying

```
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

The `netsh wlan show drivers` command yields the following:

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi

Driver                    : Dell Wireless 1820A 802.11ac
Vendor                    : Broadcom
Provider                  : Broadcom
Date                      : 04-Jan-16
Version                   : 1.566.0.0
INF file                  : oem7.inf
Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
Radio types supported     : 802.11ac 802.11a 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
Hosted network supported  : No
Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
IHV service present       : Yes
IHV adapter OUI           : [00 10 18], type: [00]
IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcmihvsrv64.dll
IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {aaa6dee9-31b9-4f18-ab39-82ef9b06eb73}
IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

I see the `Hosted network supported: No` line, but I can enable the hotspot manually through the Settings menu, shouldn't I be able to do the same from the command line then?

I have searched for the solutions, and the fix that most people suggest (enabling the Microsoft Virtual Hotspot Adapter) doesn't work because I don't have it in my device manager.

How can I fix this error? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Wireless Hosted Network requires：

1. A Hosted Network capable wireless adapter is installed in the local computer.
2. The driver for the wireless adapter must implement the wireless LAN device driver model defined by Microsoft.

Please contact the wireless adapter manufacturer/supporter, confirm with them about the compatibility/supportability for Wireless Hosted Network. Besides, make sure that your adapter has the appropriate driver installed. Or, you can try to install different driver version in compatibility mode.

> I see the Hosted network supported: No line, but I can enable the hotspot manually through the Settings menu, shouldn't I be able to do the same from the command line then

“Connect to suggested open hotspots” is Wi-Fi Sense setting, it is different from “Hosted network supported”. Based on the screenshots, “Hosted network supported” has been not enabled.

> I don't have it in my device manager.

Please try to open Device Manager – View - select Show Hidden Device. Then, check to see if you can find it in section Network adapters, or, Other devices.

Besides, you may try to manually re-start WLAN AutoConfig service and check the result.

Comment: I tried reinstalling the driver, no dice. I will contact the manufacturer. However, what I meant by "I can start the hotspot manually" is that I can host a network and share the internet connection by going to the settings menu. My logic was that if I can enable it manually, I can surely do so from the command line.